# Is there a name for this French Toast variation?

Tags: food-identification

Recently we made french toast for lunch at home.  However there was come miscommunication, and my better half made pikelet mixture instead of prepping the milk/eggs mix one would normally expect.

Pikelet mix would be similar to pancake or flapjack or perhaps even waffle mix, a somewhat thick-but-runny liquid, that can still be poured slowly.

So I dunked toast-bread slices in pikelet mix and pan-fried it like french toast.  We ate it with various toppings, like butter, syrup, or cinnamon-sugar.  Would have gone very well with Bacon too.

We jokingly called it "german toast" for no other reason than its next to french toast.

Is this pikelet/pancake-dunked fried bread known by an existing name ?

Comment: Sorry there were no photos taken at the time, and there's none left cos it was delicious :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you made is generally called batter dipped French Toast, which a lot of people say is better than regular French toast, and you seem to agree. I may have to try it!

There's one person calling the recipe [German Toast](https://www.mrbreakfast.com/superdisplay.asp?recipeid=1167), so you aren't alone, but it isn't a common name for it. German Toast is one of the alternate names for French Toast no matter how it's made.

Comment: If it were waffle batter, would it be belgian toast?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting way to cook, good thing you didn't get confused :) In general, the principle of cooking described by you implies that you cooked French toast. But I think that variations such as "pancake toast" is also a good description of your dish, although it is not so fundamental.